# Can you add objects to a List from a GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to add items to a List from a GroupBy but my results are not coming out grouped.

```
var r = from c in choreValues.ToList()
    group c by new{
        c.OpId, c.FNumber
    } into cGroup
    select new Chores(){
        FNumber = cGroup.Key.FNumber, OpId = cGroup.Key.OpId,
        Lessons = ///how do i create list of Lessons from choreValues??
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like this in the `select new Chores{}`? ***(obviously this is pseudo code)***

```
Lessons = new List<Lesson>{} from ocGroup.where(x => x.FNumber == ocGroup.FNumber)
```

For reference choreValues.ToList() looks like this prior to grouping:

```
FNumber | OpId | LName | LAge
-----------------------------
1     1       abc      7

1     2       farm     12

1     3       bike     7

2     4       abc      7
3     4       abc      7
4     5       abc      7
```

My results should look something like this, but instead it's creating a separate one for each Lesson.

```
{
  {
    "FNumber":1
    "OpId":1
    "Lessons":[
    {
      "LName": "abc", 
      "LAge": 7
        },
    {
      "LName": "farm", 
      "LAge": 12
        },
    {
      "LName": "bike", 
      "LAge": 7
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what my objects look like:

```
public class Chores{
    public short FNumber {get;set;}
    public Int OpId {get;set;}
    public List<Lesson> Lessons {get;set;}
}
public class Lesson{
    public string LName {get;set;}
    public int LAge {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you were close:

```cs
var query = 
    from c in choreValues
    group c by new { c.OpId, c.FNumber } into cGroup
    select new Chores
    {
        FNumber = cGroup.Key.FNumber, 
        OpId = cGroup.Key.OpId,
        Lessons = cGroup.Select(x => new Lesson
        {
            LName = x.LName,
            LAge = x.LAge
        })
        .ToList()
    };

var r = query.ToList();
```